# Erro ao chamar função ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho obtido um erro ao chamar uma função em ajax contida em um arquivo .js separado do meu arquivo .html. O mesmo não ocorre quando insiro esta função javascript dentro do meu arquivo html. A função é acionada quando clico em um botão contendo a chamada à função, como mostrado abaixo:

Componente HTML:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="modalAddPessoa" onclick="adicionarPessoa()">Incluir</button>
```

Função javascript

```js
let requestVerificationToken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();

function adicionarPessoa() {
    $("#incluirPessoas").attr("disabled", true);
    var pessoa = new Object();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: pessoa,
        url: '/PontoAtendimento/IncluirPessoaPontoAtendimento',
        headers: {
            "RequestVerificationToken": requestVerificationToken
        }
    })
    .done(function (pessoa, statusText, xhdr) {
        $('#incluirPessoas').modal('hide');
        $('#tablePessoas').append(pessoa);
    })
    .fail(function (xhdr, statusText, errorText) {
        console.log("Failed: " + errorText);
    });
}
```

Ao debugar, obtive o seguinte erro no navegador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver este problema?

Comment: provavelmente o __RequestVerificationToken ainda não existe quando o arquivo js está sendo carregado. Tente colocar essa linha dentro da função.

Comment: Aparentemente é isto mesmo. Coloquei a função javascript dentro de um $(document).ready(function () { }); e foi resolvido o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Substitua a tag head do seu arquivo HTML pela seguinte tag

```
<head Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *>
```

Para as requisições sem credenciais, o servidor pode especificar "*" como um curinga, permitindo assim que qualquer origem acesse o recurso.

Para permitir que https://developerrr.mozilla.org acesse seu recurso, você pode especificar:

```
<head Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://developer.mozilla.org>
```